# How to cover equals method in code coverage

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage

New to code coverage, would like to have some insights...

```
     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Person other = (Person) obj;
    if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((this.email == null) ? (other.email != null) : !this.email.equals(other.email)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.age != other.age && (this.age == null || !this.age.equals(other.age))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How do I cover this in jcoco code coverage.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the confusion, I'm trying to cover this piece of code in code coverage and idea on how can I do that? I'm trying to write a test case for covering this code.

Comment: Technically you need 7 test methods to test your `equals()` with different types of arguments to cover all ifs

Comment: @Ivan I've written most but I'm having problems writing the last 3 of them for the name, email and age. Will you be able to help out?

Comment: 1. Compare two persons with different names. 2. Compare persons with same names but different mails. 3. Compare persons with same names and mails but different ages. 4. Compare persons with al samel fields

Comment: @Ivan I tried doing that but one of the branch is not getting covered.
     final Person other = (Person) obj;
What does this mean?

Comment: Best way to "cover" the `equals` method is to *delete* it. No, really, I have seen big projects with hundreds of methods like this (and the corresponding `hashcode` methods) and every time it turns out that the system in question didn't really need them and would be simpler without them.

Answer (score 2):

To have this class 100% tested you should create a test for every `if` and `?:` operator. Every part of the code should be tested. For instance, the first `if (this == obj)`, you should have a test where you do

```
@Test
public void testEqualsSameObj() {
    MyClass sut = new MyClass(); // sut == system under test
    assertTrue (sut.equals(sut));
}
```

And now make the next test for passing null:

```
@Test
public void testEqualsNull() {
    MyClass sut = new MyClass(); // sut == system under test
    assertFalse (sut.equals(null));
}
```

And continue with the next condition, until you cover all branches in the code.

You can take the `sut` from the method and store it in the test class as a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

The equals could have 0% coverage because you might have not included the lombok.config file with with generated annotations as true.
Set,

config.stopBubbling = true;

lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true

in lombok.config file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the what method you are trying to get covered. What I understood from your question is: you are trying to cover equals code of the person.

So in order to cover that
1) have your name property of current object which referred by this as null
2) have your name property of current object as not null to cover the equals part of the code.

To understand more on this learn how ternary (? :) operator works.

I hope this answer helps.

Comment: Hello, I've added the whole method to be covered in code coverage can you please explain how to do that? I'm confused on this line 
     final Person other = (Person) obj;