# (getClass() != obj.getClass()) for Object obj

Tags: java, object

> Blockquote

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (this == obj) {
    return true;
}
if (obj == null) {
    return false;
}
if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
final Person other = (Person) obj;
if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
    return false;
}
if ((this.email == null) ? (other.email != null) : !this.email.equals(other.email)) {
    return false;
}
if (this.age != other.age && (this.age == null || !this.age.equals(other.age))) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

I have a question about this code from [this discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901324/how-to-cover-equals-method-in-code-coverage)

There is this line:

```
    final Person other = (Person) obj;
```

after this conditional statement:

```
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
```

If `getClass()` returns class that is other than `Object`, for example, most likely `Person` in this case, then wouldn't it return `false` and the rest of the code after the conditional statement not be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

The `obj.getClass()` will return the runtime class of the object, that is it will check at runtime what is the `Object` reference is pointing to.

This is mentioned in the [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) of the `getClass()` method:

> Returns the runtime class of this Object

As a simple test you can see for yourself that the `getClass` checks for the runtime type of the object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hello";
    test(s);
}
public static void test(Object o){
    System.out.println(o.getClass());
}
```

Here the output will be referring to `String` class, although the reference type at compile time is `Object`:

```
class java.lang.String
```

So in your method the `false` won't be returned if a `Person` instance is passed to the `equals` method. But if it is not a `Person` instance then the `getClass() != obj.getClass()` will be `true` and the `equals` will exit with `false` as the return value.